# Running Kotlin programs in IntelliJ Offline

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, android-developer-api, offline-mode

Can you help a newbie? How can I create and run a Kotlin project offline? Whenever I try, I get the run icon greyed out.

Comment: Do you use a Gradle or Maven project? When you are offline, it may not import correctly as it will not be able to download Gradle distribution and dependencies, so IDE will not configure the project structure/roots correctly. Try creating IntelliJ project type instead: https://i.imgur.com/NxeI8Bg.png.

Comment: For whomever is voting to close this as general computing, please [read the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) carefully: "software tools commonly used by programmers" are on-topic.  Questions about using software are only off-topic if they do not "directly involve tools used primarily for programming."

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.